# An interrupted boot followed by failed install on a Dell Inspiron

Tags: boot, dual-boot, updates, uefi, live-usb

So my brother was (finally) updating to 16.04. The laptop suspended due to inactivity during the install, which interrupted the update. When he awakened it, the update failed, and he could no longer boot his computer in Ubuntu.

So I made a live USB to reinstall 16.04 over the old partition, but during the install I got an error saying

> grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/

Without a GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.
Now there is no usable boot menu other than that of the live USB.

What steps should I take next?

As far as I know I currently cannot access Windows, but if I could find a way, would a factory reset work?

Answer (score 1):

If you could boot the recovery partition by pressing an F-key during boot, that would wipe Ubuntu and restore windows fully.

I would use that live usb session to mount your old partitions under /mnt, chroot into /mnt, and then use grub-install to reinstall grub to the hard drive.

[How to Install Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)